# From where does outlook takes display name for an email address?

Tags: email-server, outlook

How display name is assigned to email address? Say for an incoming mail from abc@xyz.com it shows Abc in outlook. That means this email id must be registered on some exchange server with other information. How & where is it done?

Comment: Take a look at the raw email, with headers, and you'll see `From: Foo Bar <foo@example.com>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general there are three options:

- The sender email address `user@example.com` gets recognised.
  Typically because that address already exists in the recipients personal address book, the corporate address book, Active Directory etc. but maybe also from a message signature, a previous reply, a v-card etc.
  And regardless of the (lack of) display name in the actual email message,  the mail client displays the <kbd>`Contact Name`</kbd> from the associated address book entry as the sender.
- The mail client such as Outlook displays the name that the sender set and which gets included in the `From:` message header before the actual SMTP email address:
  `From: Display Name <user@example.com>`
  The mail client should show <kbd>`Display Name`</kbd> as the sender.
- The sender did not include a display name in the message and the headers show only a SMTP email address: `From: user@example.com`.
  The mail client displays <kbd>`user@example.com`</kbd> as the sender.

Comment: Yes if display name is not in Internet header it looks into its corporate address book. If it is also not there, it will show email address as display name(or just part of it before @). This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Most like the sender puts it in the actual email header like so

```
From: Blizzard Entertainment <noreply@em.blizzard.com>
```

Then your mail client displays `Blizzard Entertainment` instead of the actual email address.

Or your mail client takes the username part and does some guessing. That really depends on the client application though. So `abc@xyz.com` -> *Abc*

Comment: So from my program I'm sending an email with from address 'donotreply@xyz.com' to user1@somedomain.com & user2@xyz.com. Problem is user1 is receiving correct from address as 'donotreply@xyz.com' but user2 is receiving with from 'DoNotReply, xyz group'. Why is it so?

Comment: Read last paragraph again...